# How do I test Steamworks P2P applications with only one Steam account?

Tags: java, networking, p2p, peer, steamworks-api

I'm currently writing a multiplayer game using the Steamworks API.
I've recently run into some problems though, that is I can't seem to be able to send packets from one client to another.
The API is correctly initialized and everything, but when I look for available packets, the returned packet size is always 0.
I think this is because I've only got one steam account, so Steamworks is using the same steam ID for both clients which causes problems.

So my question would be: How would one go about testing such applications, that have to use different Steam IDs? 
If you've got any other idea why the packets are not sending please let me know as well.
All the networking code is contained in one class called the NetworkManager, which I will post here (Notice that I discarded the callback methods that are not used for simplicity. connectToLobby() is called once at startup, pollPackets() is called every frame):

```
public class NetworkManager implements SteamMatchmakingCallback, SteamNetworkingCallback, SteamUserCallback, SteamUtilsCallback, SteamAPIWarningMessageHook {

private static final String LOBBY_MATCHING_KEY = "[key:sandbox-lobby]";
private static final String LOBBY_MATCHING_VALUE = "[true]";

private static final int DEFAULT_CHANNEL = 1;

private SteamMatchmaking matchmaking;
private SteamNetworking networking;
private SteamUser user;
private SteamUtils utils;

private Gson serializer;

private SteamID host;

private World world;

public NetworkManager(World world) {

    this.world = world;

    matchmaking = new SteamMatchmaking(this);
    networking = new SteamNetworking(this, API.Client);
    user = new SteamUser(this);
    utils = new SteamUtils(this);

    serializer = new Gson();

    utils.setWarningMessageHook(this);
}

@Override
public void onSteamShutdown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onWarningMessage(int severity, String message) {

    System.out.println(message);

}

public void connectToLobby() {

    System.out.println(user.getSteamID().getAccountID());

    matchmaking.addRequestLobbyListStringFilter(LOBBY_MATCHING_KEY, LOBBY_MATCHING_VALUE, LobbyComparison.Equal);
    matchmaking.requestLobbyList();

}

public void pollPackets() {

    int packetSize;
    while ((packetSize = networking.isP2PPacketAvailable(DEFAULT_CHANNEL)) > 0) {

        System.out.println("Packet was received!");

        // A packet is available, so get it's contents
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(packetSize);
        try {
            while (networking.readP2PPacket(host, buffer, DEFAULT_CHANNEL) > 0) {
            }
        } catch (SteamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.position()];
        buffer.get(bytes);

        String json = new String(bytes);

        buffer = null;
        bytes = null;

        Packet packet = serializer.fromJson(json, Packet.class);

        world.onPacketReceive(packet);

    }

}

public void sendPacket(SteamID destination, Packet packet) {

    byte[] bytes = serializer.toJson(packet).getBytes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes.length);
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();

    try {
        System.out.println(buffer.position());
        System.out.println(buffer.limit());
        if (networking.sendP2PPacket(destination, buffer, P2PSend.UnreliableNoDelay, DEFAULT_CHANNEL)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to send packet!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sent packet to " + destination.getAccountID() + " from " + user.getSteamID().getAccountID());
        }
    } catch (SteamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bytes = null;
    buffer = null;

}

@Override
public void onLobbyMatchList(int lobbiesMatching) {

    if (lobbiesMatching == 0) {

        // No open lobbies found, so create one
        matchmaking.createLobby(LobbyType.Public, 2);

    } else {

        // Open lobby found, so join it

        SteamID firstLobby = matchmaking.getLobbyByIndex(0);
        matchmaking.joinLobby(firstLobby);

    }

}

@Override
public void onLobbyCreated(SteamResult result, SteamID steamIDLobby) {

    if (result == SteamResult.OK) {

        matchmaking.setLobbyJoinable(steamIDLobby, false);

        if (!matchmaking.setLobbyData(steamIDLobby, LOBBY_MATCHING_KEY, LOBBY_MATCHING_VALUE)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to set lobby matching data!");
            return;
        }

        matchmaking.setLobbyJoinable(steamIDLobby, true);
        host = null;

        System.out.println("Lobby creation successful!");

    } else {
        System.err.println("Lobby creation failed: " + result);
    }

}

@Override
public void onLobbyEnter(SteamID steamIDLobby, int chatPermissions, boolean blocked, ChatRoomEnterResponse response) {

    host = steamIDLobby;
    System.out.println("Lobby join response: " + response);

    sendPacket(steamIDLobby, new JoinPacket());
}

@Override
public void onP2PSessionRequest(SteamID steamIDRemote) {

    System.out.println("Session request");

    // Accept any user that tries to send you messages
    networking.acceptP2PSessionWithUser(steamIDRemote);

}

@Override
public void onP2PSessionConnectFail(SteamID steamIDRemote, P2PSessionError sessionError) {

    System.err.println("Session connect failed!");
    System.err.println(sessionError);

}

}
```

The Packet class:

```
public class Packet {

public static final int PACKET_LOGIN = 0x0001;

private final int type;

protected final Map<String, String> data;

public Packet(int type) {

    this.type = type;

    data = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any hints why the packets are not received, or how I would run two clients using two different Steam IDs.

Answer (score 2):

I created a second Steam account only for this reason. Added the account as a developer to the Steamworks backend, and used a beta key to activate the game.

It's still a pain to test, since both sides need to run their own Steam client, at least as far as I know. I've just been using two machines (one PC, one MacBook), and had to constantly remind myself to sync every code change.